# Alfresco 5.0.d windows - NoClassDefFoundError: Main

Tags: alfresco

Does anyone know how to get Alfresco 5.0.d running on windows?  Each version of alfresco seems to have a nuance to get it to run on windows, I can't seem to find the nuance for 5.0.d.

tomcat error:
Commons Daemon procrun stderr initialized java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Main

Tried:
-default basic install with built-in java
-uninstalled, installed again using jdk8 JAVA_HOME instead of supplied version.
-changed JAVA_HOME to jdk7
-tried running tomcat from the commandline

All with the above error.

Comment: Could you give more info about the exception you get? Could you describe more which steps you followed during the installation process?

Comment: also, have you tried the bitnami alfresco package for windows? That seems to be working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an old issue, but just in case someone encounters it...

Can you check if you have a `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable? If you do, can you try deleting that variable and re-installing Alfresco?

We encountered this problem, and hopefully fixed it in the next releases. Here is the reference in Alfresco issue tracker: https://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/ACE-4709